# Accept string input from keyboard in LISP

Tags: lispworks

am really new to LISP. I am using LispWorks and having issues on how to accept string input from the keyboard. Here is my code below compiles well but when I run, it gives an error:

> "End of file while reading stream #<Synonym stream to
> *BACKGROUND-INPUT*>."

```
(defun get-input (prompt)
  (clear-input)
  (write-string prompt)
  (finish-output)
  (let ((x (read-line)))
  (write-string x)
  (close x)))

(write-string (get-input "Enter a sentence: "))
(finish-output)
```

I have tried all sorts of codes using "read" to no avail, someone pls help.

Comment: Don't call `close` on `x`, it's not a stream, but the value returned by `(read-line)`.

Comment: Thank you but It still doesn't work without that. I just need a simple code that accepts sentence to a variable.

Comment: Works for me if I remove the `(close x)` from your `get-input` function. But you say "accep a sentence to a variable", what do you need to do exactly ? Do you need to print the string back to the user who entered it ? Do you want your function to *return* the string that was given ? Do you want to *modify* a global variable that holds this value ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want the function to return the string and get the reverse of the string, another function. For instance if "Thank you sir",  the reverse should be "Sir you Thank".

Answer (score 0):

The code below solved my problems:

```
(defun split-by-one-space (string)
    (loop for i = 0 then (1+ j)
          as j = (position #\Space string :start i)
          collect (subseq string i j)
          while j))

(defun rev_string()
    (let ((mystr (read-line *query-io* NIL "")))
    (terpri)
        (format t "The Original String is : ~a~%" mystr)
    (terpri)
    (format t "The Reversed String By Character is : ~a~%" (reverse mystr))
    (terpri)    
    (format t "The Reversed String By Word is : ~a~%" (nreverse (split-by-one-space mystr)))))
(rev_string)
```